# What I need to do to see database items(foreach loop)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, mysqli

**What I need to do to see database items(foreach loop)?**

I have already created a database. I want to see the each mysql database item_name inside the each li tag. Can it be done with foreach loop? What I need to do for that? Can anyone give me solution for that with the code below?

Here is the code what I have now:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.cont{
      margin:200px 400px;
   width:500px;
   background:transparent;
   color:black;
   padding:20px;
   box-shadow:1px 1px 4px 4px #ddd;
  }

ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
 }
  
ul li{
   float:none;
  }
  
.m-a-d{
       display:inline-block;
    color:black;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.4;
    transition:0.3s;
   }
   
ul li:hover .m-a-d{
                text-decoration:underline;
    opacity:1;
      }
```

```html
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "a1");

if(!$conn){
 
 echo "Not Connected with localhost";
 
}

?>

<?php

require_once "init.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";

$query = $conn -> query($sql);

$rowcount = $query -> num_rows;



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<body>

<div class="cont">

<h1>To do</h1>

<?php if(!empty($items)): ?>

<ul>

<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

<li>
<span class="list"><?php $item['item_name']; ?></span>
<a href="#" class="m-a-d">Mark as done</a>
</li>

<?php  endforeach;?>

</ul>

<?php else: ?>

<p>You haven't added any item yet.</p>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help...............................

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer in what you are looking for in the output, currently it isn't clear what you want to see.  You can remove the CSS from the question as it's probably not relevant.

Comment: @Nigel Ren, I have updated my code and information about the question. Please read. I want to see the each item_name from database inside the each li tag.

Comment: The code loop looks okay, so if it's not working what errors are you getting or what is the output that you are seeing and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: @Azeame, Set a variable $items. I don't know what should I write in $items to work foreach loop. I saw a video tutorial and that was in pdo. I am not using pdo. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0yFN1GBW2w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated php code.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "a1");
    if(!$conn){
        echo "Not Connected with localhost";
    }
?>
<?php
require_once "init.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$resultSet = $conn -> query($sql); // here I replaced variable name to resultSet
$rowcount = $resultSet -> num_rows;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <body>
        <div class="cont">
            <h1>To do</h1>
            <?php if($rowcount > 0): ?>
            <ul>
            <?php while($item = $resultSet->fetch_array()){ ?>
            <li>
                <span class="list"><?php $item['item_name']; ?></span>
                <a href="#" class="m-a-d">Mark as done</a>
            </li>
            <?php }?>
            </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
            <p>You haven't added any item yet.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Majorly, you were trying to check `$items` in if condition and `foreach` while there is no result set or variable named `$items.

So I updated with `$resultSet` around line 10 and then updated code accordingly.